# Want to Develop a Web Page which will Upload and Delete File from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to build an application which will implement following functionalities

It will displays the filenames in my google drive account

Each file has a Delete File button that can delete the file from my google drive account

Page has a Add File button that lets me upload a new file to my google drive account

Each file has a View File button. If the file is a PDF, display the PDF file in the browser using any open js library of your choice. If the file is not a PDF, download the file to the computer.

Please suggest code or any link or api.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question? How do you currently upload files?

Comment: Yes I can include javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's all possible with [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk). It is well documented and there is a lot of guides and wide variety of languages you can use.

I think the most appreciate for you will be JavaScript. [Link to JS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js)

Comment: I have made retrieve file list using Google Drive Rest Api and upload file using ASPSnippent. This ASPSnippet is giving a dll that is really helpful.